# Number of permutations that do not let odd numbers be fixed points.

Tags: combinatorics

Find number of permutations of set ${1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}$ that do not let odd numbers be fixed points.

May it be done without bringing up disorder?

Comment: You could try inclusion-exclusion.  Start with all the permutations, then subtract all those that fix a particular odd slot, then add back those that fix two particular odd slots, and so on.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'fixed points'?

Comment: @Alex the concept of fixed points is very well understood for permutations.  Treating a permutation $\pi$ as a bijective function from $S$ to $S$ (*usually $S=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ but need not be*), then a fixed point is an $x$ such that $\pi(x)=x$.  Permutations without fixed points are called derangements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: You can use an inclusion-exclusion argument similar to the one used to derive the formula

$$D_n=n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$

for the number of derangements of $[n]$.

Let $S=\{1,3,5,7,9\}$, and for $k\in S$ let $A_k$ be the set of permutations of $[9]$ that fix $k$. If $\varnothing\ne I\subseteq S$,

$$\left|\bigcap_{k\in I}A_k\right|=(9-|I|)!\;,$$

since the $9-|I|$ elements of $[9]\setminus I$ can be permuted arbitrarily. It follows from the inclusion-exclusion principle that

$$\left|\bigcup_{k\in S}A_k\right|=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq S}(-1)^{|I|+1}(9-|I|)!=\sum_{k=1}^5(-1)^{k+1}\binom5k(9-k)!\;,$$

since $S$ has $\binom5k$ subsets of size $k$. This is the number of permutations of $[9]$ that fix at least one of $1,3,5,7$, and $9$, i.e., the number that you *don’t* want, and from here it’s straightforward to get the number that you *do* want.