# Derive an expression for $a_n$

Tags: combinatorics

I started studying on the subject of discrete Mathematics and I came across the following question:

Let $a_n := \lvert\{\pi \in S_n : \text{$\pi(i) \neq i$ for all odd $i$}\}\rvert$ denote the number of bijections $\pi\colon [n] \rightarrow [n]$ with no odd fixed points.

Now, I have to find an expression of $a_n$, so I started using the inclusion–exclusion theorem.

Since we have no odd fixed points I thought about the following:
\begin{align*}
D_n &= n! - \frac{1}{2} {n\choose1}(n-1)! + \frac{1}{2^2} {n \choose2}(n-2)! + \dotsb + \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n {n \choose n}(n-n)! \\
D_n &= \sum_{r=0}^{n} \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^r {n \choose r}(n-r)! \\
D_n &= \sum_{r=0}^{n} \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^r \frac{n!}{r!} \\
D_n &= n! \sum_{r=0}^{n} \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^r \frac{1}{r!}.
\end{align*}

However I am not sure whether this is the right way to find the number of derangements when we have no odd fixed points.

Comment: `oeis([sum(1 for pi in Permutations(n) if all(is_odd(e) for e in pi.fixed_points())) for n in range(2, 7)])` is your friend.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean

Comment: @MartinRubey is [suggesting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4589260/derive-an-expression-for-a-n#comment9663063_4589260) [SageMath code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwlyjEKwzAMBdCraJQgFNql18gegjFYLh8SyVg29PglzfyeK4K3mCc_qXqnBoLRqv2cIw-4BZsQKuXjYETyUljlX_WaDY-Kr5bUHDaCRW60C3u2j_Jrobfs8gOf1SMZ&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), I think. \\ For TeX, please don't switch in and out of math mode mid-formula; it destroys TeX's ability to do spacing.  For example, not `$a_n$ := |{$\pi$ $\in$ $S_n$ …` but `$a_n := |\{\pi \in S_n …$`.  I edited accordingly (lost in migration).

Comment: You seem to be guessing rather than counting. How many $r$-element sets of odd numbers are there? It sure is not $\frac1{2^r}\binom nr$

Comment: I already thought that, but I am not sure how to count it correctly

Comment: So start slowly. How many odd numbers are there in $[n]$?

Comment: If n is even then n/2 and if n is odd then n/2 + 1

Comment: If $n$ is odd, $n/2+1$ is not an integer.

Comment: yeahh i mean for odd n/2 + 1/2 = 1/2(n+1)

Comment: All right, that’s better (assuming $[n]$ denotes $\{1,\dots,n\}$). Can you write $n/2$ for even $n$ and $(n+1)/2$ for odd $n$ as a single expression using $\lfloor\dots\rfloor$ or $\lceil\dots\rceil$ so that you don’t need to keep tracking two cases depending on the parity?

Comment: So this was another way of how I tried it erlier today; however I have no clue how to combine it. I was quite sure for the "even" part but I am stuck on the odd part and how to simplify it

Comment: For the 'even' part I got:

$a_n = n! (\sum_{r=0}^{n/2} (-1)^r{n-r \choose r}$

Comment: And where did you get $\binom{n-r}r$? If a set has $n/2$ or $(n+1)/2$ (or $(n-1)/2$ in the even case) elements, how many $r$-element subsets does it have?

Comment: By setting 2/n in the summation; but now I am not sure. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: I just gave you a hint: *If a set has $n/2$ or $(n+1)/2$ (or $(n−1)/2$ in the even case) elements, how many $r$-element subsets does it have?*

Comment: Solution in the case $n=9$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988035/number-of-permutations-that-do-not-let-odd-numbers-be-fixed-points